# Is this the right way to consume a webservice with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, afnetworking

I am currently implementing the connection from the app to my webservice, at the moment I am trying to figure out what's the right way of doing this. I decided to use the AFNetworking library for the connection and handle the JSON output via AFNetworking too. I read here, that the best way to implement such an asynchronous is the usage of a callback delegate. Here are the links to my two classes. I would really enjoy some tipps and critic on my implementation and especially what to improve.

[ViewController](http://pastebin.com/AUfPhD58)

[WebServiceClass](http://pastebin.com/FQtbNdG4)

Code:

```
#import "SLLoginViewController.h"

@interface SLLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation SLLoginViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sharedWebService = [SLWebService sharedWebService];
    [sharedWebService setDelegate:self];
    [sharedWebService login:@"test@hotmail.de" withPassword:@"12345"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(NSString *)name withResult:(NSDictionary *)result andError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
@end
```

WebService

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@class SLWebService;

@protocol SLWebServiceDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)requestFinished:(NSString *)name withResult:(NSDictionary *)result andError:(NS

Error *)error;

@end

@interface SLWebService : NSObject
{
    NSURL *baseURL;
    AFHTTPClient *client;
}
@property id <SLWebServiceDelegate> delegate;

+ (id)sharedWebService;

- (void)login:(NSString *)email withPassword:(NSString *)password;

- (NSError *)generateError:(NSString *)description domain:(NSString *)domain;

@end

#import "SLWebService.h"

@implementation SLWebService

@synthesize delegate;

+ (id)sharedWebService
{
    static SLWebService *sharedWebService = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedWebService = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedWebService;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.domain.de/"];
        client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)login:(NSString *)email withPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email":email, @"password":password};
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"login.php" parameters:params];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
        NSString *result = [JSON objectForKey:@"result"];
        if ([result isEqualToString:@"fail"])
        {
            [[self delegate] requestFinished:@"login" withResult:nil andError:[self generateError:[JSON objectForKey:@"reason"] domain:@"de.Searchlight.WebServiceError"]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSDictionary *dic = @{@"firstname":[JSON objectForKey:@"firstname"], @"lastname":[JSON objectForKey:@"lastname"], @"gender":[JSON objectForKey:@"gender"]};
            [[self delegate] requestFinished:@"login" withResult:dic andError:[self generateError:[JSON objectForKey:@"reason"] domain:@"de.Searchlight.WebServiceError"]];
        }
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *err, id JSON)
    {
        [[self delegate]requestFinished:@"login" withResult:nil andError:err];
    }];

    [operation start];
}

-(NSError *)generateError:(NSString *)description domain:(NSString *)domain
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : description};
    error = [NSError errorWithDomain:domain code:200 userInfo:userInfo];
    return error;
}
@end
```

Comment: Post your code in your question instead of linking to pastebin. Otherwise you risk having your question being downvoted and closed. See the [faq] for details.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking is a great choice! I'd advise to use blocks, keeping the login request & result handling together.  It would also simplify and shorten the code.

Then, like the AFNetworking's [Getting Started](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) at the end suggests, it's a good idea to subclass `AFHTTPCLIENT`.

General remark: As the marvellous [Objective-C Phrasebook](http://www.amazon.de/Objective-C-Phrasebook-Developers-Library-Chisnall/dp/0321813758/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1357947485&sr=8-3)  suggests, a singleton can be created without GCD using the language's `+initialize`.  And the shared variable generally is a static, instead of an instance variable.

The first part would look like:

```
@class SLWebService;

@interface SLWebService : AFHTTPClient

+ (SlWebService)sharedWebService;

- (void)login:(NSString*)email 
     password:(NSString*)password
      success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSDictionary* response))success
      failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error))failure;

@end

#import "SLWebService.h"

@implementation SLWebService

static SLWebService*  sharedWebService;

+ (void)initialize
{
   if ([SLWebService class] == self)
   {
        sharedWebService = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.de/"]];

        // Let AFNetworking do conversion to/from JSON.
        [sharedWebService setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [sharedWebService setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
        [sharedWebService registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    }
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    if (sharedWebService && [SLWebService class] == self)
    {
        [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Duplicate SLWebService singleton creation"];
    }

    return [super allocWithZone:zone];
}

+ (SLWebService*)sharedWebService
{
    return sharedWebService;
}

...
```

As a final off-topic remark: I don't like Apple's/Xcode's suggestion to use `-initWithNibName::` for view controllers, because this keeps the XIB name outside the class.  You almost never need to initialise with a different XIB, therefore I'd rather specify the XIB inside '-init'.  Like so:

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"SLLoginView" bundle:nil])
    {
    }

    return self;
}
```

Cheers, hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, but I am still curious about what you meant with the usage of blocks. Is the way to use a delegate wrong in this situation? The communication between my ViewController and my WebService is the point where I struggle the most. Because later on many diffrent view controllers are accessing the WebService.

Comment: As a style, blocks seem nicer/better.  With a delegate you'll end up with a additional methods that are also removed from the place where you called the web-API.

Comment: Imagine you'd need to load web-content at a user's button tap. Using blocks you'd call one of your own `AFHTTPClient` subclass methods (e.g. `-getXyzContent::`).  In the success block, that's part of that method call, you'd show the received content in the view.  In the error block you'd inform the user.
In other words: When using blocks you'll have self-contained `AFHTTPClient` subclass methods you can use anywhere in your code, including view controllers. You can typically call these methods in user action code, in `-init`, or `-viewDidLoad` as you've done already.
Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok, so I call the login method from my viewcontroller with my success and failure block and define these two blocks in my viewcontroller right?